Dynamically change the configuration of Tailwind with Nuxt 3
guys! I have a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to. I need to change the tailwind configuration depending on the data I receive from the backend.
Why the whole config? It should be something like a site builder where the admin can change the site design among the available ones, and that's why I want to change the whole config, specifying colors for the design and content in it, so that Tailwind doesn't create classes for all designs at once, because it's not optimized. This option is quite scalable and convenient.
I was able to do this to some extent, but this option only works when building a project. In it, I use a module inside which there is a tailwindcss:loadConfig hook, where I pass an asynchronous function as one of the arguments, in which I send a request to the server, receive a json object with which I replace the configuration. This option works, but I don't think it will be very convenient for users.
export default defineNuxtModule({
    setup(options, nuxt) {
        nuxt.hook('tailwindcss:loadConfig', async (tailwindConfig) => {
            const config = {
                content: [
                    './assets/presets/**/*.{js,vue,ts}',
                ],
                theme: {
                    extend: {
                        colors: {
                            'admin-main': '#000bff',
                            'admin-secondary': '#07e024',
                            'admin-background': '#F1F1F1',
                            'disabled': '#da17ca',
                            'dark-gray': '#4A4A4A',
                            'border-secondary': '#DDDDDD',

                            // Primevue
                            'primary-50': 'rgb(var(--primary-50))',
                            'primary-100': 'rgb(var(--primary-100))',
                            'primary-200': 'rgb(var(--primary-200))',
                            'primary-300': 'rgb(var(--primary-300))',
                            'primary-400': 'rgb(var(--primary-400))',
                            'primary-500': '#1937f1',
                            'primary-600': 'rgb(var(--primary-600))',
                            'primary-700': 'rgb(var(--primary-700))',
                            'primary-800': 'rgb(var(--primary-800))',
                            'primary-900': 'rgb(var(--primary-900))',
                            'primary-950': 'rgb(var(--primary-950))',
                            'surface-0': 'rgb(var(--surface-0))',
                            'surface-50': 'rgb(var(--surface-50))',
                            'surface-100': 'rgb(var(--surface-100))',
                            'surface-200': 'rgb(var(--surface-200))',
                            'surface-300': 'rgb(var(--surface-300))',
                            'surface-400': 'rgb(var(--surface-400))',
                            'surface-500': 'rgb(var(--surface-500))',
                            'surface-600': 'rgb(var(--surface-600))',
                            'surface-700': 'rgb(var(--surface-700))',
                            'surface-800': 'rgb(var(--surface-800))',
                            'surface-900': 'rgb(var(--surface-900))',
                            'surface-950': 'rgb(var(--surface-950))'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://meowfacts.herokuapp.com/', {method: 'GET'});
                const result = await response.text();
                newConfig = Object.assign(tailwindConfig, config)
                // tailwindConfig = config
                console.log(tailwindConfig)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
    },
})


I want to be able to do this dynamically, without restarting the project. Is there any way to change the configuration in a fully compiled application? And also configure Vite to track configuration changes and recompile Tailwind, as it is done when you add a new class to the page?
I am not a very experienced Nuxt and Vite user, so I hope for your support

There are ways of using it on the fly with Tailwind: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn Some other packages do the same, so that you build the CSS given a specific config fetched from a sever. Meanwhile, if you use a build step as shown here, it will not work without another build to update the config.
